# Cucumber: fill in a field with double quote in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have some rails app, a view with a field, lets say its called 'some_field'
I want to fill in in the field '"SOME_STRING_WITH_QUOTES"'

How can I do this in cucumber?

```
When I fill in "some_field" with ""SOME_STRING""

When I fill in "some_field" with "\"SOME_STRING\""
```

dont work (the cucumber parser doesnt seem to approve)
What to do? Its not some sort of matcher, so a regex wont work neither

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you write a step in your cucumber scenario, Cucumber suggests you the standard regex to match text inside the double quotes (regular expression [^"]* means a sequence of 0 or more characters of any kind, except " character). So for `When I fill in "some_field" with: "SOME_STRING"` it will suggest the following step definition:

```
When /^I fill in "([^"]*)" with: "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1, arg2|
    pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

But you are not forced to use this regex and free to write any matcher you want. For example the following matcher will match any string that follows after colon and ends at the line end (and this string may include quotes):

```
When /^I fill in "([^"]*)" with: (.*)$/ do |field, value|
    pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Then your scenario step will look like this:

```
When I fill in "some_field" with: "all " this ' text will ' be matched.
```

## Update

You can also use Cucumber's [Multiline String](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Multiline-Step-Arguments) in your Scenario step:

```
When I fill in "some_field" with: 
  """
  your text " with double quotes
  """
```

And then you won't need to change step definition generated by Cucumber:

```
When /^I fill in "([^"]*)" with:$/ do |arg1, string|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Your string with quotes will be passed as a last argument. In my opinion this approach looks heavier than the first one.

Comment: Thanks, I hoped there was a more general solution without having to write a step for it (e.g. an escape character I couldn't find about)

Comment: If your string contains double quotes but does not contain single quotes, then you may surround it into single quotes in the scenario step and change regex appropriately.

Comment: @SirLenz0rlot , I added one alternate solution

Comment: Thanks a lot, i tried both solutions and agree with you the first solution results in a cleaner cuccie.

Comment: You can also arg1.gsub('\\', '') the quotes out if you escape them in your original feature.

Answer (score 2):

While google'ing I just found [an alternative solution](http://til.developingego.com/post/944561627/escaping-quotation-marks-within-quotation-marks-in) which is (imho) more easy to understand (or reunderstand ;)). I'm using Java but I'm sure the same idea could be reused in your case..

Instead of using this step definition:

```
@Then("parameter \"(.*?)\" should contain \"(.*?)\"$")
```

I use another escape char (from " to /):

```
@Then("parameter \"(.*?)\" should contain /(.*?)/$")
```

So I can write the feature using double quotes:

```
Then parameter "getUsers" should contain /"name":"robert","status":"ACTIVE"/
```

Answer (score 0):

below works perfectly.

```
When I fill in "some_field" with '"SOME_STRING"'
```