# Escaping characters in cucumber step definition

Tags: cucumber, escaping, bdd

I have used following step def for capture error message from given pop up modal

```
Then warning "Invalid file. File name should be "Users.xml" " should be given to user
```

In this case I want to include "User.xml" inside the given string

```
@Then("^warning \"([^\"]*)\" should be given to user
```

But this will not escaping the ". How do I escape this " character for matching the exact string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need to change

`@Then("^warning \"([^\"]*)\" should be given to user`

to

`@Then("^warning \"(.*?)\"  should be given to user$"`

`[^"]*` is matching everything except quotes

`.*?` will match everything (including quotes )

For more information See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533943/cucumber-fill-in-a-field-with-double-quote-in-it)

You can also use multiline string to do that as explained in above link

Also see this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMEmACa4PG0) for including strings in your arguments

Comment: I am glad, I could help